# SQL giving me different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I run this two queries separately and combined the output in excel it gives me the correct results

```
select
    DISTINCT userid
  from
    table1
  where
    event like '%signup%'
    and date(root_tstamp) between '2022-02-01'
    and '2022-02-07'
    and userid is not null and userid <> ''),
```

and

```
    select
        DISTINCT user_id,
        geo_country
      from
        table2
      where
        geo_country is not null
        and geo_country <> ''
        and user_id is not null
        and user_id <> ''
        and date(etl_tstsmp) between '2022-02-01'
        and '2022-02-07'
```

But if I ran it on as a single query with CTE it gives me the wrong results as following query

```
with base1 as ( select
    DISTINCT userid
  from
    table1
  where
    event like '%signups%'
    and date(root_tstamp) between '2022-02-01'
    and '2022-02-07'
    and userid is not null and userid <> ''),
base2 as (
  select
    DISTINCT user_id,
    geo_country
  from
    table2
  where
    geo_country is not null
    and geo_country <> ''
    and user_id is not null
    and user_id <> ''
    and date(etl_tstamp) between '2022-02-01'
    and '2022-02-07'
)
select
base2.geo_country,
base1.userid
from base1
inner join base2 on base1.userid = base2.user_id
```

any suggestion

Comment: *it gives me the wrong results* - what does that mean? Presumably they are returning different `user_id` so an inner join will only give you rows common to both. Have you considered a `union`?

Comment: Off the top of my head it looks like you have unmatched rows in table1 and table2. i.e. table1 has a user_id in that table2 doesn't and/or vice versa. Have you checked that both tables return exactly the same set of id's?

Comment: @AdamBenson, I want only the match same userid in both table.

Comment: @Stu, Yes it is what I want result only common for both.  Wrong results means that when I run queries separately and combined with use of excel gives me total 31000 rows and that is the correct the number, but I run with CTE it gives total of 52000 rows which is wrong.

Comment: When you conbine your results in Excel (however you are doing that) you are not *joining* your data sets. It looks like you might not understand that *distinct* applies to the entire row, so in `base2` if user A has two distinct `geo_country` values, that's 2 rows for that user in the results.

Comment: @stu, In excel id did using vlookup, to do that I exported from database using mentioned two queries. So how can I combine only one instance of base2 userid to base1.

Comment: Note that the `DISTINCT` belongs to `SELECT`, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT`. As it is written now, it looks like you want a distinct column - which is very misleading.

Comment: I don't know, there is no sample data and desired results in your question, if user A appears once in your first query (because it's distinct) but two or more times in your second query (once for each distinct geo_country), which geo_country do you want? you probably need to be aggregating and grouping instead of blindly distincting rows.

Comment: @Stu, first match would be enough, no need a particular method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I suspect you need to change your *base2* query to an aggregation, something like

```
select user_id, max(geo_country) geo_country
  from table2
  where
    geo_country is not null
    and geo_country <> ''
    and user_id is not null
    and user_id <> ''
    and date(etl_tstamp) between '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-07'
  group by user_id
```

There is also no need for joining two separate CTEs, you can simply use the above query and implement an *exists* for your first query, correlating on user_id, ie,

```
select user_id, max(geo_country) geo_country
from table2 t2
where <criteria>
and exists (
  select * from table1 t1
  where t1.user_id=t2.user_id and <base1 criteria>
)
group by user_id
```